# Change column from results select

Tags: mysql

how can I update all results of a selected issue?

In the "reason" column have the text NULL, unfortunately the text is NULL and not "mysql null"

I would now like to delete the text NULL so that the length is 0, i.e. empty

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE reaseon LIKE 'NULL'
```

how can i change them all at once now?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple update should work if i understand your question correct:

```
update db set reaseon = null where reaseon ='NULL'
```